# No response from PHP on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on a simple signup page using jQuery and PHP using AJAX.

Here is the script for making the ajax call:

```
<script>
    function submitForm(){
      var data1=$('#regform').serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'signup.php',
        data:data1,
        success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
          if(response==1)
            alert('taken');
            else if(response==2)
              alert('registered');
              else
                alert(response);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
```

and the PHP script which responds to the call:

signup.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
if($_POST) {
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $user_password = $_POST['password'];  
    try {
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM logindata WHERE email=:email");
        $sth->execute(array(":email"=>$user_email));
        $count = $sth->rowCount();   
        if($count==0){    
            $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO logindata(username,email,pass) VALUES(:uname, :email, :pass)");
            $sth->bindParam(":uname",$user_name);
            $sth->bindParam(":email",$user_email);
            $sth->bindParam(":pass",$user_password);   
            if(!$sth->execute()) {
                echo "3";  
            } else {
                echo "2";
            }
        } else{    
        echo "1"; 
        }    
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

using PDO.

dbconnect.php:

```
<?php
  $dbhost='localhost';
  $dbuser='root';
  $dbpass='';
  $dbname='ambitio';  
  try{
    $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }
  catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }  
?>
```

**Problem**

Neither of the two responses are being returned to the jQuery ajax call. I checked with `console.log()` but nothing shows up in the browser. Data gets stored in the MySQL database (checked it) which means that `execute()` is working fine in PHP, but still no alert is shown in the browser. `1` does get returned in case `count` evaluates to `0`.

Also, when I refresh the form without actually submitting the form, I get the error `POST 412 (Precondition Failed)` at the browser console.

**Apache access log**

```
::1 - - [19/Jul/2016:23:51:55 +0530] "GET /ambitio/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/ambitio/signup.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [19/Jul/2016:23:51:55 +0530] "GET /ambitio/css/overboot.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/ambitio/signup.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [19/Jul/2016:23:51:55 +0530] "GET /ambitio/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/ambitio/signup.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [19/Jul/2016:23:51:55 +0530] "GET /ambitio/js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/ambitio/signup.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [19/Jul/2016:23:51:55 +0530] "GET /ambitio/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/ambitio/signup.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [20/Jul/2016:00:43:36 +0530] "GET /ambitio/signup.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1454 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [20/Jul/2016:00:43:46 +0530] "POST /ambitio/signup.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1454 "http://localhost/ambitio/signup.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [20/Jul/2016:00:43:46 +0530] "POST /ambitio/signup.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "http://localhost/ambitio/signup.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
```

**Form HTML markup**

```
<form method="post" id="regform" onSubmit="submitForm()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="user_name" name="user_name" />
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="user_email" name="user_email" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Retype password" id="rpassword" name="rpassword" />
      <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It is not a asynchoronous call ?

Comment: Is display errors enabled on the server?  If not, what does your apache access and error logs say?  Is the server seeing the request?  Does it log a failure before returning a result?

Comment: Okay, I see that the server is being hit by the request with the given logs, and there are (presumably) no 500 errors.  Now what does your browser debugger show for the request?  In Firebug, you should see a `POST` line in the Console.  In Chrome and others, you should get a line listed under the NET tab or something similar.  What do you see in your Headers and Response sections for that (if any) request there?

Comment: @chris85 did it, but still nothing on the console.

Comment: If Console tab is empty that's mean your submitForm wasn't call.

Comment: @SuperJer In Firebug, Headers: https://postimg.org/image/83k60hvvz/ and the Response contains the html code for the page containing the script.

Comment: That is sending to `signup.html`?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Your AJAX says `url:'signup.php'` why is it going to `.html`?

Comment: @chris85  The `signup.html` is the file which has the AJAX script, I have two files here: `signup.php` and `signup.html` . Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Oh, I thought the screenshot was of the AJAX submit. What does the AJAX request look like? Just to confirm the AJAX is going to `signup.php`, not `.html`..

Comment: @JayBlanchard Added form markup.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: @chris85 `signup.php` is receiving the AJAX request. https://postimg.org/image/4t4zs3kq7/

Comment: I'm running on localhost. There is no error related to the AJAX or the PHP but on refreshing the page generates `POST 412 (Precondition Failed)`.

Comment: HTML markup of `signup.html` is returned as response as seen from firebug.

Comment: Okay, what does the `POST` tab contain?

Comment: @chris85 Here is the `POST` tab: http://postimg.cc/image/ju7a9d3fz/

Comment: I find it interesting that there really isn't anything listed for Response under the Headers tab.  Check to see if the script is getting the post data by putting something like this at the top of your signup.php: `file_put_contents('postdata.txt', date('G:i:s  ').print_r($_POST, true));`  Run it, then move the line below your connection `require()`, then in your `if()` block, etc.  That'll write the time, and the contents of your $_POST to the file.  Useful for finding out where the breakdown is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your form doesn't contain a url to send to and your `onSubmit`-Handler (`submitForm`) doesn't return `false`, the form will actually get posted by the browser to the page it's currently on (which is most likely not capable of processing the form's POST data) and will just reload the login-form containing page.

The POST will likely be send to your ajax script **as well**, but your browser won't wait for the reponse, because it already moved on.

See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#concept-form-submit for further details on the submit process.

Solution would be to either add `return false` to your `submitForm` function or to the `onSubmit` handler (`;return false`)

Comment: This solved the problem, thanks for the info. Learned a lot from the link you provided.